# Phoenix v1.3 app not rendering view index.html in Prod

Tags: heroku, phoenix-framework

The page loads perfectly on localhost, but when trying to access it live, I get an internal server 500 error. The Heroku log output:

`(Phoenix.Template.UndefinedError) Could not render "index.html" for Driverless.Web.MainplayersView, please define a matching clause for render/2 or define a template at "lib/driverless/web/templates/mainplayers". No templates were compiled for this module.`

What can cause this.  I'm 99% sure I have all of the correct files.

**Controller**

```
defmodule Driverless.Web.MainplayersController do
  use Driverless.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    render conn, "index.html"
  end
end
```

**View**

```
defmodule Driverless.Web.MainplayersView do
  use Driverless.Web, :view
end
```

**templates/mainplayers/index.html.eex**

```
//Just a load of html.
```

**Router**

```
defmodule Driverless.Web.Router do
  use Driverless.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", Driverless.Web do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PostController, :index
    resources "/posts", PostController
    get "/about", AboutController, :index
    get "/mainplayers", MainplayersController, :index
  end

  # Other scopes may use custom stacks.
  # scope "/api", Driverless.Web do
  #   pipe_through :api
  # end
end
```

Could it be a typo in a file name somewhere? Not sure why it works fine on local machine, but not on Heroku.  Other static pages load fine.

Comment: Is the template in lib/driverless/web/templates/mainplayers or web/templates/mainplayers?

Comment: It's in lib/driverless/web/templates/mainplayers

Comment: Is driverless a sub-project? The reason why I ask is that the `lib` and `web` folders for a phoenix project are both normally at the root of your folder structure

Comment: This is the new structure in v1.3